# aws sam application: s3 bucket with a preload shared config file

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, serverless, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I would like to deploy a shared configuration file for my sam application.
Creating the s3 bucket is a no-brainer. But how would I upload my config file during deployment.

What I got so far is:

```yaml
....

ConfigBucket:
  Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
  Events: 
     Fn: Transform:
       Name: AWS::Include
       Parameters:
         Location: config.yaml
....
```

Unfortunately this results into an error. `/Users/myuser/code/sam-project-folder/.aws-sam/build/../../config.yaml no such file or directory`

The config file is in the root of my `sam-project-folder`. I have also tried `./config.yaml` `../../config.yaml` and `config.yaml`.

How would one create a s3 bucket and upload a file during sam deploy (no additional cli, etc) in `template.yaml`. Am I on the right path with my approach?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to uploading the file during the SAM deployment ?